# C++ accessing elements of an array

Tags: c++, arrays

Normally we access an array element in this manner: `arrayName[elementID]`. But even we use like `elementID[arrayName]` it compiles and does not cause any errors in runtime. Isn't it logically wrong? Can anyone explain me this. I'm new to C++. Thank you in advance for any help!

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[4] = {2, 4, 5, 7};
    cout << arr[2] << endl; //this is the correct way to use it 
    cout << 2[arr] << endl; //this gives the same result and does not cause any errors
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `[]`s are (approximately) syntactic sugar for pointer addition with a dereference, and addition is commutative.

Comment: When asking other people to read your code, please put spaces around operators and after commas. It makes it easier for us to help. I already edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following are equivalent:

```
a[b] == *(a + b) == *(b + a) == b[a]
```

It really doesn't matter which one you use, so long as it's readable and it conveys the intent of the programmer.

Comment: I would ask another question - is this a feature or bug in C++ caused by backwards compatibility with C (personally I think `2[array]` must be a compile error), but I think it's offtopic for SO...